# PHP setcookie to resemble ASP.Net Cookie subkeys

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies

ASP.Net has the concept of using 'subkeys' in cookies.  i.e. You can write a cookie with

```
Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "patrick"
Response.Cookies("userInfo")("lastVisit") = "today"
```

This would create a cookie which looks like

```
Name:   userInfo
Value:  userName=patrick:lastVisit=today
```

Is there a native method in PHP to read/write cookies like the above one?

I need to read/write a cookie in PHP which can be read by ASP.Net with subkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write such a cookie:

```
$userInfo = array(
     'userName'  => 'patrick'
    ,'lastLogin' => 'today');

$userInfo = str_replace('&', ':', http_build_query($userInfo));
setrawcookie('userInfo', $userInfo);
```

to parse the cookie back into an array:

```
$userInfo = parse_str(str_replace(':', '&', $_COOKIE['userInfo'));
```

Comment: I'm particularly facing problems while writing a cookie in this format:"subkey=value:subkey2=value". PHP is having problems writing unescaped data to the cookie too. It converts '=' to %3D

Comment: Yes I could user urldecode, but I'll have to rewrite all ASP.Net code to do a similar manipulation. Is there any way the cookie can contain "userName=patrick:lastVisit=today" instead of " userName%3Dpatrick%3AlastLogin%3Dtoday" ?

Comment: use setrawcookie() instead of setcookie()

Comment: Also, take note that `parse_str` for whatever reason returns void and instead expects a second "optional" parameter. So it should be `parse_str(str_replace(':', '&', $_COOKIE['userInfo'),$userInfo);` ... What a backwards language

Comment: I don't think that's right - you need to use ampersands instead of colons... `userName=patrick&lastLogin=xxxx` is the format you want. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx - "Subkeys are laid out much like a query string in a URL"

Answer (score 1):

`setrawcookie()` is a solution for that.