# How to make PHP's "array" cookies look like ASP.Net's?

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies

Heello, I'm writing a script in PHP that I need to be compatible with ASP.Net.

When you use a cookie as an array/dictionary in ASP.Net, it will generate a cookie like this:

```
Set-Cookie: examplecookie=name=test&secret=blahh&expire=1341130948; path=/; HttpOnly
```

However, PHP's built in cookie/dictionary functionality seems to save separate cookies for each key/value.

Before I go write a script to serialize an array into something like this... Is there any built in methods of doing something like this?

Comment: The cookies functions are the same no matter what language you use (javascript, PHP, asp, asp.net etc). I think that you serialize your data before you save it (maybe in PHP have a similar function that saves it not serialized or something), and thats why they saved that way. Show here the way you save them to give you some more information's.

Comment: @Aristos I know they're "the same" but they don't serialize multiple keys/values the same way

Comment: I found my answer at this question of which mine is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109944/php-setcookie-to-resemble-asp-net-cookie-subkeys